# Turn on and turn off standby mode the Samsung TV web app

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I made a samsung web app, and my problem is the app should run e.g 7:00-20:00. Out of this time (20:00-7:00) it should turn on the standby mode. Any suggestion to solve this problem? The app just playing some pictures in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API for that. I am not sure if you have access to the B2B forum, so I am going to assume that you don't. Look for these methods:

```
setOnTimer()
getOnTimer()
setOffTimer()
getOffTimer()
setOnTimerRepeat()
getOnTimerRepeat()
setOffTimerRepeat()
getOffTimerRepeat()
setOnTimerVolume()
getOnTimerVolume()
setHolidayToTimer()
getHolidayToTimer()
```

in the documentation available to you.

An example from the B2B documentation, which I assume is posted elsewhere online as well:

```
var onSuccess = function(val) {
  console.log("[setOffTimer] success : " + val);
};
var onError = function(error) {
  console.log("[setOffTimer] code :" + error.code + " error name: " +  error.name + "  message " + error.message);
};
console.log("[setOffTimer] ");
b2bapis.b2bcontrol.setOffTimer("TIMER6","21:30", onSuccess, onError);
```